# Android web UI Performance is dramatically slower than iOS (why?)

Tags: android, ios, performance-testing, nexus-7

I wanted to test android for a html5/Javascript web app, so I purchased a Nexus 7 (2nd gen), and upgraded the OS to the lastest 4.3.

The Nexus has substantially better specifications than my old test iPad 2:

- 2GB ram vs 512MB
- 1.5GHz x 4cores vs 1GHz x 2cores

However I'm finding the Nexus UI interaction on web pages is between ~5-10 times slower than the iPad. Button presses, animations and the like are *very* laggy. For example a button press flipping from pressed to unpressed on the iPad 2 keeps pace with as fast as your finger can twitch, even when drumming two fingers, (greater than 5/sec). Whereas the Nexus is noticeably lagging behind the user touch at less than 1/sec. In fact Android/Nexus is so slow it sometimes misses the un-touch event, leaving the button in the depressed state.

I am trying to get the the bottom of this, is it a limitation in the OS? A problem with the hardware? (this is googles own device though) Is the Java JVM overhead limiting performance? (though I'd think that Chrome is all native C/C++). Is there a fix?

I ran an Browser javascript test (Dromaeo), and the computational results are what you'd expect (the newer fast Nexus was around 2x the speed of the old iPad). Though I did notice that oddly the iPad out-performed the nexus in DOM manipulation tests by around 2x, though still not as dramatic as in the user experience.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of Web App ? Any JS framework used ? They may not be optimized for Android 4.3

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think the developer has any access to hardware acceleration calls directly inside the browser. In both cases I'm using Chrome, so that should be the same.

Comment: You cannot compare iOS vs Android OS , as their architecture design is completely different. Generally, iOS has better graphical performance than Android OS, as you can see from many multiple-platform apps.

Comment: I tested the behavior with Jquery Mobile, Enyo.js, kendoUI, and Sencha touch. Some are better than others, but Android lags in all of them.

Comment: They may be different, from a UI speed a developer *has* to compare them. If you can't make responsive web apps, then Android is off the table as a viable option.

Comment: I was also experiencing the same with my web app. One easy and simple demonstration is to open the raphael.js webpage and load a demo side by side on both devices.

Comment: As others have mentioned, it's hard to compare the two one-for-one.  After all, you are comparing performance at the very top of the technology stack.  Although, if responsiveness/delay (not necessarily pure processing ability) is the issue, you might find this relevant: http://venturebeat.com/2013/09/19/apples-iphone-5-touchscreen-is-2-5-times-faster-than-android-devices/